# What is causing these flush processes?

Tags: ubuntu, ps

What are these `flush` processes?

```
$ ps aux | grep flush
root       710  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S     2012   2:29 [flush-202:1]
root     10732  6.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr14 453:33 [flush-202:80]
ubuntu   24009  0.0  0.0   8080   900 pts/3    S+   06:26   0:00 grep --color=auto flush
```

I notice that the `flush-202:80` process often jumps to the top of `top`. This is on Ubuntu Server 12.04 running Apache, MySQL, and Solr processes. Googling the subject I found [another SF post](https://serverfault.com/questions/341123/flush-processes-consume-too-much-of-cpu) which mentions that these processes should never consume much CPU. The solution presented in that post mentions to reboot the system, which is exactly how I came to poke around in `top` and discover the processes in the first place: [the system won't reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283089/ubuntu-server-not-shutting-down-on-command).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numbers tell you what the flush process is working on. Do

```
grep ^ /sys/class/block/*/dev
```

and you will see something like

```
:
/sys/class/block/sda1/dev:8:1
/sys/class/block/sda2/dev:8:2
/sys/class/block/sda5/dev:8:5
/sys/class/block/sda6/dev:8:6
/sys/class/block/sda/dev:8:0
:
```

compare this with your `ps ax | grep flush`

```
10213 ?        S      0:00 [flush-8:0]
```

and you can see that what `flush` is working on is my `/dev/sda`.

You could probably get more info by doing

```
grep "201:80" /proc/self/mountinfo
grep "201:1" /proc/self/mountinfo
```

and

```
lsof | grep "201,80"
lsof | grep "201,1"
```

to see what processess have opened what files on these devices.

What does `top` show you before and while this is going on? It would be best to track the problem down rather than do a reboot. Once you find the process that is causing the problem you might be able to tune `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio`, `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs` and `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio` to compensate.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I am already accepting the answer as there is quite a bit for me to learn in there. תודה ושבת שלום!‏